# C# Excel don't ask for sign in

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an application that is used on multiple computers and they all access a excel document, the problem with that is is that when 2 users use it at once, the users will get an error that the file is in use by someone else.

I fixed this by setting it to open as readonly but the problem with this is that it's asking me to sign in ("Type the email of the account you would like to open ... with")

This is not very practical if every user has to sign in, is there a way to skip this? If I close the prompt it works as normal though.

```
excApp = new Excel.Application();

excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Open(strWkbLocation, ReadOnly: true);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the prompt `Type the email of the account you would like to open ... with`... is coming from Excel? Or somewhere else. Also have you tried to make the Excel file a template? As this would also solve the multiple opening of the same file without using the read only option.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `Workbook.Open` is:

```
Workbook Open(string Filename, object UpdateLinks, object ReadOnly, object Format,
    object Password, object WriteResPassword, object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended,
    object Origin, object Delimiter, object Editable, object Notify, object Converter, 
    object AddToMru, object Local, object CorruptLoad);
```

So the third argument is `ReadOnly` and the seventh is `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended`.

It probably wouldn't hurt to also disable app warnings, although I don't think that's necessary:

```
excApp = new Excel.Application();
excApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Open(strWkbLocation, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
excApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

I'm not saying it's not possible, but I don't know of a way to surgically define a parameter the way you do in VBA (as in your example).